# why isn´t this code appending event.xdata and event.ydata from plot to list?

Tags: python

I´m trying to append event.xdata and event.ydata from a matplotlib plot to two lists that are outside the "onclick" function but when I print those lists they are empty. 
Can someone explain me why?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.plot(np.random.rand(10))

start_values = []
finish_values = []

def onclick(event):
    print 'button=%d, x=%d, y=%d, xdata=%f, ydata=%f'%(
        event.button, event.x, event.y, event.xdata, event.ydata)
    x_values = event.xdata
    y_values = event.ydata
    start_values.append(x_values)
    finish_values.append(y_values)

cid = fig.canvas.mpl_connect('button_press_event', onclick)

print(start_values)
print(finish_values)

plt.show()
```

Thanks in advance for your help.
Kind Regards. 
Ivo Roupa

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears to be working fine.  You're just printing the list values before `plt.show()`, and therefore before the user has any chance to interact with the plot. Do let me know if I've misunderstood, though.

Just as a side note, `plt.show()` blocks further execution of the script until the plot window is closed.  If you wish to update the plot with the user's interaction, try `show(block=False)` - it is still listed as an experimental argument, so it may not work if you have an older version of the package.

Comment: Thank you for the help about plt.show(), I wasn't aware. Is there a way to pass those values to a variable without closing the window, because I need to extract some values for several times for some calculations and keep the window opened. Ivo

Comment: The data is being appended to your arrays while the window is still open - that's not a problem, it all ready works fine.  If you with to perform calculations while the window is still open, the easiest way would be to do them in (or call them from) the `onclick` function.  If that doesn't answer your question, please expand on what you're trying to do.

Comment: I will try to explain my situation. I have 1 time serie with an angle from 10 times 1 person sitting and standing up. In that serie during the first 2 seconds the angle is pretty much the same and after I have "10 plots" - 1 for standing up and sitting. To process data I need to split the time serie in 10 subplots. That said I would like to click with the mouse over the first and last frame for  each plot and print that value for visual inspection and also add those values to a list to count plot number and max and min for each plot. Thanks for your help. Ivo